# external link icon

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using a script, that works great. It pops in a external link icon next to external links. Whoopydoo... and also adds a target="_blank" attribute.

The issue I have is, I dont want it to work on IMAGES.

Only on text links , so any sugestions.

The jquery is:

```
(function(a){
a.fn.link_external_icon=function(p){
    var p=p||{};
    var icon_path=p&&p.icon_path?p.icon_path:"link_external.png";
    var n=a(this);
    n.find("a[target='_blank']").css("padding-right","13px").css("background-image","url("+icon_path+")").css("background-repeat","no-repeat").css("background-position","center right");
}
```

})(jQuery);

The Script is:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("body").link_external_icon({
                icon_path:"../images/link_external.png"
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Image is: [image]

Any help appreciated.

Original code is: http://htmldrive.net/items/show/161/Link-external-icon-jQuery-plugin-for-show-external-linktarget_blank-icon.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your selector to...

```
n.find("a[target='_blank']:not(:has(img))");
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/DDXmm/).

#### Your plugin, modified

(as per requested in comments.)

```
(function(a){
a.fn.link_external_icon=function(p){
    var p=p||{};
    var icon_path=p&&p.icon_path?p.icon_path:"link_external.png";
    var n=a(this);
    n.find("a[target='_blank']:not(:has(img))").css("padding-right","13px").css("background-image","url("+icon_path+")").css("background-repeat","no-repeat").css("background-position","center right");
}
```

Comment: So I have :  a.fn.link_external_icon=function(p){
        var p=p||{};
        var icon_path=p&&p.icon_path?p.icon_path:"link_external.png";
        var n=a(this);
        n.find("a[target='_blank']").css("padding-right","13px").css("background-image","url("+icon_path+")").css("background-repeat","no-repeat").css("background-position","center right");
What should it be ? sorry to be dense

Comment: @422 That much code in a comment is almost impossible to read. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Cheers Alex, many thanks. That worked PERFECT :) Voted up and chosen. Many thanks